# How to cite multiple authors from one edited anthology Harvard style

Tags: citations

Here's a question that's nagging me. I want to cite different authors from one edited anthology in Harvard style inline citations. Note, this is not for one particular quote, but throughout the paper I want to cite one author here and then another there. Do I just use the editor's name for the inline citation (Jones, ed. 2016: 114) or do I cite the particular author each time I do this (Robinson in Jones, ed., 2016: 114) in order to give each author I use his/her due?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Harvard referencing, you would use the following:

Surname author, Initial(s) (Year) 'Title of chapter', in Surname editor, Initial(s) (ed.) Book title in italics. Edition. Place: Publisher, page.

I.e:

> Beizer, J.L. and Timiras, M.L. (1994) 'Pharmacology and drug
>   management in the elderly', in Timiras, P.S. (ed.) Physiological basis
>   of aging and geriatrics. 2nd edn. Boca Raton: CRC Press, pp. 279-284.

[This site here](http://www.ntnu.no/viko/english/papers/harvardlist) has a handy reference guide for numerous publication types.